# How to make a list of Plots of derivatives of a function?

Tags: functions

I did that..
i don't see what i did wrong. How would you do this?
I want to use it for ListAnimate.

```
Table[Plot[(fuu^Times[i, '])[x], {x, fromX, toX}, PlotRange -> 2, 
      PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {i, 0, 3}]

Table[Plot[D[i][fuu[x]], {x, fromX, toX}, PlotRange -> 2, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {i, 0, 3}]

Table[Plot[(fuu^i)[x], {x, fromX, toX}, PlotRange -> 2, 
      PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {i, 0, 3}]
```

My Solution(with help of fabian):

```
Table[functionAndZerosPointsPlot[D[fuu[x], {x, n}]], {n, 0, 4}]
ListAnimate[%]
```

Comment: …what is `fuu` supposed to be?

Comment: an arbitrary function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want?

```
Func = Sin[x] Exp[x^2];

Plot[Table[D[Func, {x, n}], {n, 1, 4}] /. x -> y, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Or as individual plots:

```
tp = Table[D[Func, {x, n}], {n, 1, 4}]
Table[Plot[tp[[n]], {x, 0, 1}], {n, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.. but it was confusing that you use the y for the x axis.. :)

Comment: Why the `x -> y`? Because if you use `{x, 0, 1}` as 2nd argument to `Plot`, then for each such `x`, *Mathematica* will evaluate all those derivatives with respect to the currently-constant value of `x`, which makes no sense mathematically and would give a *Mathematica` error.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative solutions. One involves the use of the `Derivative[]` operator:

```
f[t_] := Sin[t] Exp[t^2]
Plot[Table[Derivative[n][f][x], {n, 1, 4}], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

while the other uses the built-in function for the "scaled" derivative:

```
Plot[Table[n! SeriesCoefficient[f[\[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], x, n}],
           {n, 1, 4}], {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

where the option setting `Evaluated -> True` allows `Plot[]` to render the different curves in different colors.